# Question regarding asymptotic distribution and the second order delta method

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

Assume that $\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}_n - \mu) \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$ and assume that $\mu=0$. I wish to apply the second order delta method, to find the asymptotic distribution of
$$
\sqrt{n} ( \bar{X}_n^2 ).
$$
I have shown that for any twice continuously differentiable function $f$ (in some neighborhood of $\mu$), that
$$
\frac{n(f(\bar{X}_n) - f(\mu)}{\sigma^2} \stackrel{d}{\to} \frac{f''(\mu)}{2} \chi_1^2
$$
however, how would we proceed from here, to determine the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n^2$? My original thought was to apply the continuous mapping theorem, however, with no luck. Furthermore, we can write
$$
\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{n(f(\bar{X}_n) - f(\mu))}{\sigma^2}
$$
for $f$ defined as $x\mapsto x^2$. What are we able to say?

Any hints would be lovely, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The technique behind the delta method is the Taylor's approximation. You have:
$$f(\bar X_n) =-f(\mu)+(\bar X_n-\mu)f'(\mu) + \frac{1}{2}(\bar X_n-\mu)^2 f''(\mu) + \mathcal{o}((\bar X_n-\mu)^2)$$

We denote:
$$\sqrt n (\bar X_n - \mu) \xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2):=X$$
Then with $f(x) = x^2$:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n^2 - \mu^2) &\stackrel{\mathcal{D},n\infty}{=} \sqrt n (\bar X_n - \mu) \cdot2\mu+\frac{1}{2}\cdot2 \sqrt{n} (\bar X_n-\mu)^2+ \mathcal{o}(\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)^2)\\
&\stackrel{\mathcal{D},n\infty}{=} \underbrace{\sqrt n (\bar X_n - \mu)}_{\to X}\cdot2\mu+\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \underbrace{\left(\sqrt{n} (\bar X_n-\mu)\right)^2}_{\to X^2}+ \mathcal{o}(\underbrace{\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)^2}_{\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt n}X^2}) \\
 &\stackrel{\mathcal{D},n\infty}{=} 2\mu X+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X^2+\mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X^2 \right) \\
\end{align}$$

For $\mu = 0$, you have:
$$\sqrt{n}\bar X_n^2  \stackrel{\mathcal{D},n\infty}{=}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X^2+\mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X^2 \right)  \tag{1}$$

*Remark 1:* A more orthodox way of writing $(1)$ is
$$n \bar X_n^2 \xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{\mathcal{D}} X^2  $$

*Remark 2:* If you want, you could use Taylor's approximation of higher order to get the higher terms of $(1)$ (however, as we all know, these terms are negligeable by comparing to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X^2$).

Comment: Firstly, I have never encountered the notation$\stackrel{\mathcal{D}, n \infty}{=}$. Does it simply stand for convergence in distribution as $n\to \infty$? Secondly, what originally threw me off was the $n^{-1/2}$ on the RHS when we have taken the limit as $n\to \infty$, is this allowed? Then I guess we can write that $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n^2 \stackrel{d}{\to} \Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2\sigma^2}{\sqrt{n}}   \right) $? Best regards,

Comment: @BreeZeriNoo yes, it simply stand for convergence in distribution as $n \to +\infty$. Secondly, math notation is just a mean to convey the ideas, so, allow or not depend on the person with whom you communicate, for me, there is no problem to write like this (because we two understand what is behind this notation). However, some people just like the orthodox way (as I wrote in the *Remark 1*), and for them, it’s not correct to write $\Gamma(1/2, \frac{2\sigma^2}{\sqrt n}$.)